# PowerShell Repeatedly calling a function

Tags: function, powershell, workflow

The task at hand is to compare permissions from a source folder with a target folder, and this for all its sub folders. I've already created the function that does this check on one folder, which returns `$True` or `$False`.

I would like to know if it's possible to create a function that calls itself to be executed on every sub folder it finds to call `Test-ACLequalHC`. So that when it blocks or errors out in one of the sub folders, due to permission issues or something else, it can still continue with the others.

Something like a crawler, if that makes sense. Ideally it would be great if it could run in parallel. I read that a `Workflow` is most suited for this, but I've never used it before.

Unfortunately it's not possible to just do `$AllSubFolders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse` followed by a `foreach`, because there are over thousands of files and folders under the root folder. So it needs to be dynamically so that we can do extra stuff on every folder it finds, like say if `Test-ACLequalHC` results in `$False` on one folder, we can still call other functions to set the permissions correct or add the result to a CSV.

**Permission test:**

```
Function Test-ACLequalHC {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [String]$Source,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [String]$Target,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
        [ValidateSet('Access','Owner','All')]
        [String]$Type
    )
    Begin {
        $Props = Switch ($Type) {
            'Access' {'Access', 'AreAccessRulesProtected'}
            'Owner'  {'Owner'}
            'All'    {'sddl'}
        }
    }
    Process {
        $CompParams = @{
            Property         = $Props
            ReferenceObject  = Get-Acl $Source #| Sort-Object
            DifferenceObject = Get-Acl $Target #| Sort-Object
            PassThru         = $True
        }
        $Result = Compare-Object @CompParams 
        if ($Result -ne $null) {
            Write-Output $false
        }
        else {
            Write-Output $True
        }
    }
}
```

It would be great if it could check files to, for inheritance and that no extra permissions are added. But I'll add that stuff later on myself if I find out how to make such a `crawler` thingy that digs its way through the folder structure.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have two paths: source and target. For the recursion task which do you intend to check the children on? Would the source stay the same and you would check more files similar to target? How far does this recursion go. How do you decide that `-recurse` is too much to process? Just trying to figure out what you could use in place of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory`

Comment: "when it blocks or errors out in one of the sub folders, due to permission issues or something else, it can still continue with the others."
See the ErrorAction common parameter when calling your function
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/09/hey-scripting-guy-march-9-2010.aspx

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your help. I think I do need to use `Get-ChildItem` but not `-Recurse`, as this would generate too much at once to handle and doesn't allow iteration from top to bottom. The source folder serves as a static example, with the correct permissions set. The target can have more or less folders/files, and can have very much data. That's why I think it would be appropriate if the function does one `Get-ChildItem`, does it's thing and moves on for the next `Get-ChildItem` based on the previous output (calling itself). So it goes downwards one by one, and not all at once.

Comment: Not confident enough for this to be an answer but would not have a `end` block in your function that would call itself?. Something like `Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Directory | ForEach-Object{ Test-ACLequalHC arguments}` This would mean that you would have to write more verbose output than true or false obviously

Comment: All functions can call it self. What exactly is wrong with using Get-ChildItem -Recurse? Is it just the fact that it take forever?

Comment: Hi ojk, yes it will take a very long time. But if it's the only option, then that's just the way it is i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think your aversion of doing Get-ChildItem -Recurse is something you're going to need to get over. If you are only looking at directories use the -directory switch for Get-ChildItem. It's a provider level switch so it will speed things up dramatically.

Next, what I think you need to consider is the Ad--Member cmdlet. Something like this:

```
$Source = C:\GoodFolder
$AllFolders = GCI C:\ -Directory -Recurse
$AllFolders | ForEach{Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName "ACLGood" -NotePropertyValue (Test-ACLequalHC $source $_.fullname all)}
```

Then you can just filter on that for folders that have issues and address them as needed.

```
$AllFolders | Where{!$_.ACLGood} | ForEach{ Do stuff to fix it }
```

Comment: Thank you TheMadTechnician, I think you're right. I just have to suck it up that it takes a long time. On Monday at work I'll try your suggestion for the folders only and then afterwards i can do a foreach for the files.